# What are Bender's computational specifications?

Tags: futurama

As in, what kind of processor, how much RAM, and how much hard drive space does Bender have?

Also, what operating system does Bender run?

Has this been referenced in any episode of Futurama (or in any of the commentary)?

Could some of these details be theoretically worked out using Moore's law (or some other principle)?

Comment: I don't know if the specs have ever been revealed, but there's a lot of computers in Futurama with the Mac startup sound.

Comment: Whats with the -1?

Comment: +1 to balance, I'd call this a valid question.  Just worded oddly, as "spec" could be read as "species", which is just plain wrong.

Comment: I am not sure we can do a direct extrapolation using Moores Law since the planet was blasted by aliens during Fry's cryo-sleep.

Comment: Thanks guys, although I should probably do some work at some point lol!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[The Infosphere notes](http://theinfosphere.org/Bender_Bending_Rodr%C3%ADguez):

> Bender's head contains a [6502 Microprocessor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOS_Technology_6502) ([*Fry and the Slurm Factory*](http://theinfosphere.org/Fry_and_the_Slurm_Factory)), and his ass an [AMD Athlon II](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Athlon_II) ([*Overclockwise*](http://theinfosphere.org/Overclockwise)). After Cubert overclocks Bender's ass, Bender discovers that he has "an extra processor in his compartment of mystery".

So his total processor count would be 3 (head, ass, and [hammerspace](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Hammerspace)). Presumably, the third "extra processor" is also an AMD Athlon II, but it isn't specified.

Comment: Cool, although AMD Athlon II is lazy writing methinks, it's like they just Google'd 'Processor'!

Comment: @JMK - I thought the pun was he had an Athlon in his ass.  (Ath sounding similar to ass).

Comment: @drjimbob Aah I didn't get that! Duh!

Answer (score 11):

Bender runs on [MOS Technology 6502](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOS_Technology_6502#In_popular_culture).

Comment: In which case, I could hack him! Or I could have, at one point.

Comment: Mom ported TRS-DOS to the 6502? I'd always assumed Bender was a Z80 unit.


http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRS-DOS