# What is Bender made of?

Tags: futurama, bender-rodriguez

What is Bender (from Futurama) physically constructed out of?  He mentions several times that he is "XX% titanium/lead/etc" but I don't recall the specific materials and proportions.

This question [What are Bender's computational specifications?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9392/what-are-benders-computational-specifications) deals with his computational specifications but I'm interested in the physical composition of his body.

Comment: Don't forget his nickel impurity

Comment: @lois it's what made him _him_!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The list of Bender's claimed composition adds up to over 100%, so he can be a dubious source (episode codes in brackets):

- 40% Zinc (1ACV13).
- 40% Titanium (2ACV03).
- 30% Iron (3ACV22), presumably mixed with osmium, (3ACV17).
- 40% Dolomite (4ACV07).
- 40% Lead (video game).
- 40% empty (s07e09)
- 40% back (s7e21 Assie come back)
- 0.04% Nickel impurity - (3ACV17 - A Pharaoh to Remember)

There was also a claim that he was 40% chromium (not made by Bender but by someone else - 6ACV03).  In addition to those, he's also claimed to be 40% horseshoes (ITWGY), 40% Wire (7ACV03) and 40% scrap metal (6ACV23), either of which could be any of the above metals or something else.

Comment: He's 40% "whatever the writers need to be funny in that particular situation"; it's a long-running gag.

Comment: I thought it probably added to more than 100 which is why I was interested.  Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand the Episode code... What does ACV stand for?

Comment: They're the production codes - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Futurama_episodes.

Comment: It's only inconsistent if we assume his composition is static, of course.

Comment: Actually Bender has a 0.04% nickel impurity.

Comment: 100% awesome is what he is.

Comment: Of course Bender's estimates are going to be innacurate - he's self-professed that he's a bad calculator.

Comment: As a elephant seal he was 40% fat.  Season 9 Episode 13

Edit- list of more: http://futurama.wikia.com/wiki/Bender_Bending_Rodr%C3%ADguez

Comment: Don't forget, his CPU is a MOS Technology 6502!

Comment: There's no mention of the proportion accounted for by his shiny metal ass.